# why not nested syntax in Scala higher-kinded type parameter

Tags: scala, types

This is not allowed, A nested type parameter (higher-kind type, right?):

```
trait Abc[C[T]] {
    def f(): C[T]
  }

cmd13.sc:2: not found: type T
  def f(): C[T]
```

Whereas this is

```
trait Abc[C[_],T] {
    def f(): C[T]
  }
```

---

is there reason that we need to write Abc[C[_],T] instead of Abc[C[T]] ?
I mean that the latter is more intuitive.

Comment: Bikeshedding syntax is unlikely to be very productive. FWIW, I think the existing syntax is slightly better, since `C` and `T` are really two different independent variables. If anything, I would be happy if we could just leave of the `[_]` (so `trait Abc[C,T] { .. }`) and have the compiler infer the kinds (as Haskell does) based on the use-sites (and barf with an error if use-sites have conflicting kinds).

Comment: This is like writing a method `def foo(f: (Int, String) => Double) = ???` and then expecting `foo` to magically also have an `Int` and a `String` parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Abc[C[T]]` syntax is not intuitive to me: it seems to have only one argument, when it has two. Worse, consider

```
def foo[C[T]](x: C[(String, T)]): T = ...
```

What would the `foo[C[T]]` syntax convey? It seems to imply that `C[_]` is being applied to `T` later on, when it is not. The syntax `foo[C[_],T]` does not have that implication.

Since this question was tagged Haskell, let me add that in Haskell we write

```hs
foo :: forall c t. c (String, t) -> t
```

so a similar Scala syntax would be

```
def foo[C,T](x: C[(String, T)]): T = ...
```

This could be done, if Scala used kind inference to infer the kind of `C` as Haskell does. Of course, if `C` is actually unused in the type, then we would need some way to suggest its kind, e.g.

```
foo :: forall (c :: * -> *) t. ...
```

or rely on kind polymorphism (as in Haskell). This requires a more advanced typing engine, though.

In Haskell, the GHC devs like to experiment with bleeding edge research in the compiler, and the programmers enjoy that. In Scala, the devs are a bit more conservative, but still added pretty advanced things compared to most languages. After all, Scala has higher kinds, which are not widespread -- even if Scala lacks kind inference and kind polymorphism, I'd still regard Scala as quite advanced with respect to types.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason is that the with the second syntax there are many reasonable things you can't do or they would look very ugly.

1. How would you re-write something Monad-inspired like this:

```scala
def map[F[_],A,B](src: F[A], f: A=>B): F[B]
```

2. Where would you put restrictions on types? Imagine the clutter for something like this:

```scala
def sorted[S[_] <: Seq, A : Ordered](seq: S[A]): S[A]
```

So what you suggest seems like adding a syntax that simplifies the trivial case and makes more complex cases very hard or impossible. This doesn't look like a good trade-off.

P.S. I bet this question will be closed soon as mostly opinion-based because most probably this is what it is.